# How to retrieve the data from different databases in Micro Services?

Tags: database, .net-core, microservices

Currently, we are using the micro services architecture. In the landing page of our application, the user can see the list of campaigns  (Campaign Micro service) which is associated with various other parameters such as coupon id (Coupon Micro service), destination country id's (Content Management Micro service), created by user id (User management Micro service) etc., But  we need to show the coupon name, destination country names and user name rather than just showing the id's in the listing page.

How I can retrieve all this details without having any lag on the performance?

Comment: Can you speak to the intents of all the microservices? This may be one of the instances where the microservices are too "micro" and doesn't associate to a given domain and a bounded context. It sounds like all the services are basic CRUD apps.

Off the top of my head, I am thinking about using aggregates in the campaign service but that may violate data integrity when it comes to that. In order to not violate data integrity, I would suggest making the additional requests to the respective services but that contributes to network calls which has the potential of hurting performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a trade off between availability and consistency. Getting a response within a reasonable amout of time is part of the *availability* of the CAP theorem.

If you are going to implement microservices and you don't want to take the hit on performance, then you should think about data duplication. The data you need for showing this list will be duplicated in the database that your landing page has access to. But the different services (i.e. Campaign, Coupon etc) will still be the source of truth in your application landscape.

This will solve the potential performance problem, but you get the problem of keeping the data eventual consistent in return.

Comment: If we need to duplicate the necessary data which are present in the other microservices, to display the list from coupon microservices, then what will be the most effective way to maintain the data consistency across these services? So that, we can eradicate the discrepancies between them.

Comment: That depends on your architecture and it is a matter of taste. You could use a service bus or create a service that synchronizes the data. I have used both strategies in the past with no problems. Uncertainty is an important part of distributed systems. Unfortunately you will never be able to guarentee that the data is always consistent. It is a "best effort" and most of the time that is perfectly fine. I would choose one strategy and make it work as best as you can, but always have an option to manually intervene in case the strategy fails. You are going to need this some point in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much for the inputs. We are thinking to use the service buses such as RabbitMQ and NServiceBus to handle the events which will update the data in the respective databases. Since you used this strategy, could you let us know the precautions we need to take, so that we could avoid the issues which may occur in production? This will help us enormously.

Comment: That is a pretty broad subject, but basically it is being aware of your assumptions. And that is very difficult to do. Some of the things I have encountered are: messages not always received in the order that they're sent, handling a message in the other system fails (e.g. db transactions rolled back for whatever reason, connectivity issues). Handling conflicting messages (e.g. you receive a message that an order has been processed by system A, but system B has told you earlier that product is no longer in stock). It all depends on the requirements of course. Distributed computing can be hard.

Comment: It helps a lot to us. Will consider your valuable inputs and make sure that   we take necessary action to overcome the issues discussed. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Personally, I think it is a little farfetched to actually implement a message bus without understanding the complete problem altogether. The challenge with the message bus is that your entire application will have to be completely driven by events to get the same messages propagated through. Not only is it going to be for an event being processed for a campaign, but all writes now have to be event sourced. If you can, I think I would weigh whether you need such granular services first.